# Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project - Include .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer, vsto

I built a Visual Studio 2008 setup Project wich depends on .NET 3.5. I added Prerequisites like: .NET 3.5, Microsoft office interoperability, VS tools for office System 3.0 Run time, .etc. After that Selected "Download Prerequisite from Same location as my application" in Specify install location for Prerequisite. I Built the setup and found mysetup.msi in Release directory.

In a new machine I started fresh installation of my application. A dialog shows like this "*This Setup Requires .NET framework 3.5 , Please install .NET setup then run this setup, .NET Framework can be obtained from web Do you want to do that now?*" it gives "*Yes*" and "*No*" option - if I press yes it goes to Microsoft website. How can avoid it? I wanted setup take .NET Framework to be installed from same location where I put all setup files including mysetup.msi?

In case of quiet installation cmd /c "msiexec /package mysetup.msi  /quiet /log install.log" ..in log I can see only half way through installation then error Property(S): HideFatalErrorForm = TRUE
MSI (s) (D0:24) [00:07:08:015]: Product: my product-- Installation failed.
=== Logging stopped: 3/23/2010  0:07:08 ===

How can complete I the installation without user intervention and without error using VS2008 setup project?

Thanks for all the help in advance for any input.

Answer (score 6):

On a default installation of Visual Studio 2008, the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 prerequisite is not available for local installation. If you want to include the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 setup with you application installer you need to follow the instructions listed in [How to Include .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 with Your Installer](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/11/18/how-to-include-net-framework-3-5-sp1-with-your-installer.aspx).

On a side note, welcome to SO. Don't forget to check out the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get to information on how the site works.